# ConvNet Sharp "Error during calculation"

Tags: c#, conv-neural-network, convnetsharp

currenty I am developing a CNN for studying purpose. I have a proplem with ConvNetSharp. I get an exeption with the text "Error during calculation" and the networkwork stopps training. So far I could figure out the error occurs because the sgd-trainer optimizes the gradients until infinity. Am I the only one affected or does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In Debug mode, ConvNetSharp constantly checks the content of Volumes looking for **NaN** and **Infinity**.

"Error during calculation" and "Invalid input!" errors means a Volume contains invalid data.

This can be due to:

- Gradient exploding (most common case): try to reduce learning rate
- Volume with incorrect shape fed into network (this is your case
  according to what you posted on ConvNetSharp Github issue)